# Пишу бота на aiogram3 используя WebApp. Хочу получить данные с формы в бота, но не представляю как

Tags: python, aiogram-3.x, webapp2

Я сделал это так,что получаю данные через js. Как отправить данные в бота или как это можно сделать напрямую без использования js
Вот ссылка на бота https://t.me/L212earnBot_Bot